# Find the Largest possible value of the sum of the arithmetic sequence 85, 78, 71,...

Tags: arithmetic

Obviously $a=85$ and $d=-7$ but I cannot figure out how to calculate the maximum value given this?

Comment: Hint. Once the numbers are negative the sum so far decreases. When does that happen?

Comment: So the last positive term is the 13th no do I need to do 13/2(2*85+(13-1)*-7)

Comment: Yes you did....

Comment: Yes, it's correct. (Didn't see the $n-1$ there...)

Answer (score 1):

sum increases while the terms are positive, so compute the number of terms to include the last positive term. Then compute the actual sum.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Your common difference is negative. Therefore, the largest sum will be the sum of all positive terms. Recall that in an arithmetic sequence with the initial term $u_1$ and common difference $d$, the $n^{th}$ term is found by

$$u_n = u_1+(n-1)d$$

Try to find the greatest value of $n$ such that

$$u_n > 0 \implies u_1+(n-1)d > 0$$

so that you can cover all the positive terms, followed by plugging the value of $n$ to find that $u_n$. Finally sum up all the terms from the initial term to the $n^{th}$ term. You can use

$$S_n = \frac{n(u_1+u_n)}{2}$$

Comment: 85 + (13-1)*-7 = 1 does this not mean that n = 13?

Comment: Yes yes, my bad. (Didn't pay attention to the $n-1$ you wrote.)

Comment: when I use 12 I get a value one off the answer given in my book but 13 is way off leading me to believe that 12 is the correct n...

Comment: No, $13$ is the correct $n$ as you've written. Your formula looks fine as well (for $S_n$), so maybe you miscalculated for the final answer?... Otherwise, the book is incorrect.

Comment: You're right I miscalculated xD! Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: Glad to have helped.